# How are these websites full-screened in the browser with a learn more button at the bottom (moves you into automatically down the page)

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown

Websites like Heroku.com and dropbox.com display a front homepage that is full-screened automatically to your browser size, they have a button at the bottom that will automatically move you down the page to learn more about the site. How are they doing this? Can someone help me with a simple code setup?

I've made an outline here http://jsfiddle.net/WwHP6/ but I can't figure out how to do the full-screening and learn more link

HTML

```
<div class="page1">
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Support</li>
            <li>Sign Up</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="page1-content centered">
        <h1> Generic Header</h1>
        <h2> Generic Content 1</h2>
        <h2> Generic Content 2</h2>
        <h2> Generic Content 3</h2>    
</div>    

<div class="learn-more centered">
    <a href="#learn"> learn more </a>
</div>


<div class="page2-content">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

.centered {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center; 
}
nav {
  list-style: none;

}

.navigation ul li { 
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.page1-content {
    clear:both;
}

.learn-more a {
    color:red;
}

.page2-content {
    margin: 200px 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    background-size: 100% 1000px;
}
```

Comment: "full screen" is something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), I think that is what you are looking for.

Also I've created [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8C9xj/19/) how you can implement this.
Hope it will help you.

Here's a script.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                //$(this).animate(function(){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#text").offset().top
                    }, 2000);
                //});
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am bnot exactly sure what you want but hope this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/WwHP6/1/

In Short: Put a div around your "page1"-Div and make it the size of the screen.

CSS

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.page1_wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red; /* just needed to show the size auf the div */
}
```

The scrolling can be realized with simple anchor-tags. However clicking one of those will jump to the anchor but do not play an animation/transition. For this you have to use Javascript. JQuery for example offers scrollTo().